# Bitcoin 0.18: how to send bitcoin from one address to another using Bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, client, bitcoin-cli

To transfer bitcoin from one account to another address, we have used `sendfrom` method and which got deprecated in the latest version Bitcoin 0.18.0

[Bitcoin `sendfrom` method](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/sendfrom/)

On reading the document of Bitcoin 0.18.0, it is suggested to use `sendtoaddress` method.

`sendtoaddress` method has two required parameter

1. "address" - address to which we want to sent BTC
2. "amount" - amount in whole number

Unlike `sendfrom` method, there is no parameter where we can pass the parameter with account or address from which we want to send BTC.

Please let me know how can I define the account or address from which I need to send Bitcoins or is there any other method available.

I am using bitcoind to make RPC calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know how can I define the account or address from which I need to send Bitcoins or is there any other method available.

The `listunspent` and `createrawtransaction` commands together can be used to achieve what you are asking.

The `listunspent` command will give you all the UTXOs that your wallet controls. You can pass an address parameter to filter all the unspent outputs by address. The documentation of `listunspent` is available [here](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/listunspent/). This command will return you the `txid`s, output index, value and others.

Then use the `createrawtransaction` command and specify those `txid`s and output indexes in the input, and the address and value that you want to send in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your response... i checked the process of transaction and we need to sign and then send the raw transaction. Is there no straight forward method like sendfrom?